# Rename leaf subdirs with names starting in RR

Tags: shell, unix, terminal, ocaml

I am looking to rename all subdirectories whose names begin with RR and who don't have subdirectories of their own to 'A'

Comment: Why does the `ocaml` tag appear?  The hard part is identifying which directories are leaf nodes; the rest is fairly straight forward.  If you don't have to fret about newlines in directory names, `sort -r` gives you sub-directories before the directories that hold them; and `find -depth` does that too.

Comment: I was hope to find a solution in OCaml, but I'm open to whatever.

Comment: This attempt gives me an illegal option --m, any ideas? find -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d | while read dir; do mv -T "$dir" "`dirname "$dir"`/`basename "$dir" | sed "s/[rR].*$/MIC_A/i"`"; done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), if a glob wildcard doesn't match anything it will just print the wildcard character itself, e.g. If `/somedir/` does not have any subdirectories, then *after expansion* `/somedir/*/` is literary equivalent to `'/somedir/*/'`.

So a simple bash script to find all directories without subdirectories and with names beginning with `RR` would be

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -u nullglob 
while read -r dir; do
  [[ $(echo "$dir"/*/) == "$dir/*/" && ${dir##*/} =~ ^'RR' ]] && echo "$dir" 
done < <(find . -type d)
```

Should be easy to interpolate from there, but not clear what you want to do when we have multiple directories matching your criteria and can't rename them all to `A`?

To rename directories like `RRetcetc` to `A`, just change it to the following

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -u nullglob 
while read -r dir; do
  [[ $(echo "$dir"/*/) == "$dir/*/" && ${dir##*/} =~ ^'RR' ]] && mv -v "$dir" "${dir%/*}/A" 
done < <(find . -type d)
```

But again note that this doesn't take into account multiple directories matching ^RR in the same directory.

Comment: I get an error with that

sh fix.sh 
fix.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
fix.sh: line 6: `done < <(find . -type d)'

Comment: I was counting on there not being any other R folders, but thats not really a plan

Comment: @JamHam Make sure you're running it as `/bin/bash scriptname` rather than `/bin/sh scriptname`

Comment: I also tried /bin/bash ../fix.sh 
It give no error, but doesn't print anything either.

Comment: Strange. You're definitely in a directory with subdirectories named 'RR...' that don't have any subdirectories of their own?

Comment: yes indeed. I tried a few variations as well to no avail

Comment: BroSlow, Thanks, JamHam

Comment: Where should I look to insert the mv for renaming?